# How to custom FontSize in dropdown from React Native Modal Dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown

i want to change fontsize in dropdown from React Native Modal Dropdown library. because too small like this.

[image]

but, if i use dropdownTextStyle still doesn't work. this is my code

```
<ModalDropdown
                  style={{height: 40}}
                  textStyle={{fontSize: 16, paddingTop: 8, paddingBottom: 8}}
                  dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown}
                  dropdownTextStyle={{fontSize: 30}}
                  options={this.state.status_option}
                  defaultIndex={-1}
                  defaultValue={'Please select'}

                />
```

please help thhis problem

Comment: Could you paste the full style codes ?

Comment: Works fine for me? http://imgur.com/JQb4ckg

Answer (score 1):

You can be using `renderRow` props like below

add `renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}`

```
 <ModalDropdown
  ...
  renderRow={this.renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}.bind(this)}
  .../>
```

After that, define `renderRow`

```
renderRow (rowData, rowID, highlighted) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#36baac'>
        <View >
          <Text style={styles.textDropdown} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
            {rowData}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
```

So you can modify `textDropdown` style as you want.

Answer (score -1):

We can provide the css class name as part of attribute to set css for drop down.
See the code example class name "form-control" is set for drop down AnswerGroup

`@Html.DropDownList("AnswerGroup", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(ViewBag.DropDownAnswerGroup), " ---- Please Select Answer Group ---- ", new { @onchange = "GroupValues(this.value)", id = "dpanswergroup",@class= "form-control" })`

Please refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) for more information